# Is there a timeout configuration for AWS code pipeline action?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-codepipeline

I'm currently looking for a way to automatically stop a step, whether it be build or deploy if it reaches a certain threshold.

Like if the deploy step lasted for 15 minutes already, I want it to automatically fail.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=216350

Answer (score 15):

If you go into the project in
*Developer Tools > CodeBuild > Build projects > [your project]* there
should be an *Edit* button/menu with an *Environment* choice which opens a new page, in which you can extend the *Additional configuration* triangle and edit the build timeout and queued timeout.

If you Edit the Pipeline -> Edit the Deploy stage -> click on the edit icon on the deploy task, this brings up the Edit Action overlay where, for the Deploy action, you can set a Deployment timeout.

Comment: I found this thread when looking for how to set the timeout on a manual approval action. Your answer does not cover that use case (or any provider besides CodeBuild).

Comment: @tommy What's the difference between 2?